# PHP array sorting and outputting behaviour

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array

```
$arr = array('key1' => 1, 'key3' => 3, 'key2' => 2);
```

Now i want to sort the array in the descending order of value.So i tried the following

```
arsort($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Output

```
Array(
    [key3] => 3
    [key2] => 2
    [key1] => 1 
)
```

But when i tried the following i got output as `1`

```
print_r(arsort($arr));
```

Since i am doing sorting the array and then outputting in both cases why its giving me  different outputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why its giving me different outputs?

Look at the [function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php):

> bool arsort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
>
> This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their
>   correlation with the array elements they are associated with.
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

It uses a reference to array, sorts it and then you are outputting the sorted array in the first case.

In the second case you are outputting the result of the function - it returns TRUE, indicating that the sorting was successful.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `1` is outputted is because [`arsort()` returns a boolean value](http://php.net/arsort#refsect1-function.arsort-returnvalues):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns **TRUE** on success or **FALSE** on failure.

When a boolean value is turned into a string (which is called [type juggling](http://php.net/juggling)), it is [turned into either of two values](http://php.net/string#language.types.string.casting):

- `TRUE` is turned into the string `"1"` and
- `FALSE` is turned into an empty string, `""`

If you want to display the contents of the array you should first sort the array and *then* output it:

```
arsort($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Asort` returns true on success and false on failure, you are printing the sorting result, in php `Asort` changes the variable you are sorting (has side effects), when printing `Asort($arr)` you are only asking to print the return value of the function,which in this case is true.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider reading the PHP documentation of the [arsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) function, especially the return value.